# BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync() causes "BackgroundWorker does not support cancellation." error

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I need to make sure a BackgroundWoker isn't busy before being called, so I check `IsBusy` and call [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) if it is:

```
if (bgWorker.IsBusy)
                bgWorker.CancelAsync();
```

But if `IsBusy` is true, an InvalidOperationException exception occurs in `CancelAsync()` saying "BackgroundWorker does not support cancellation."

The documentation makes usage seem pretty straightforward, so what am I doing wrong? **How can I cancel the job?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341488/how-to-cancel-background-worker-after-specified-time-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to set the [BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) to true.